# SQL return second max date for each id, date and channel

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following `table`:

```
id  channel_id     date
1 | 1           | 2017-01-10
1 | 2           | 2018-02-05
1 | 1           | 2019-03-07
1 | 2           | 2020-03-15
2 | 1           | 2018-01-17
2 | 1           | 2019-07-20
2 | 1           | 2020-01-10
```

I want to return for previous maximum date for each `date` and `id` but two separate columns for both `channel_id`. So, one column for previous max date for `channel_id` is equal to 1 and another for previous max date for `channel_id` is equal to 2. What I want to get can be found below:

```
id  channel_id       date      prev_date_channel_id1    prev_date_channel_id2     
1 | 1           | 2017-01-10 |    NULL               |    NULL                |
1 | 2           | 2018-02-05 |    2017-01-10         |    NULL                |
1 | 1           | 2019-03-07 |    2017-01-10         |    2018-02-05          |
1 | 2           | 2020-03-15 |    2019-03-07         |    2018-02-05          | 
2 | 1           | 2018-01-17 |    NULL               |    NULL                |
2 | 1           | 2019-07-20 |    2018-01-17         |    NULL                |
2 | 1           | 2020-01-10 |    2019-07-20         |    NULL                |
```

I made a query as below and returns what I want but takes too much time. I'd appreciate any optimization suggestions!

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.date,
    MAX(c.date) AS prev_date_channel_id1, 
    MAX(d.date) AS prev_date_channel_id2    
FROM 
    table a         
LEFT JOIN
    table c ON a.id=c.id AND a.date>c.date AND c.channel_id=1
LEFT JOIN
    table d ON a.id=d.id AND a.date>d.date AND d.channel_id=2
GROUP BY a.id, a.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` for the previous date and a cumulative conditional max for the channel 2 date:

```
select t.*, lag(date) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date,
       max(case when channel = 2 then date end) over 
           (partition by id
            order by date
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 row preceding
           ) as prev_date_channel2
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an error in your "expected output" for the value of `prev_date_channel_id1` on the last row (it should be `2019-07-20`).

In any case, with appropriate indexing an `outer apply top 1` construct might serve you better:

```
create table t
(
   id int, 
   channel_id int, 
   [date] date 
   constraint pk_t primary key clustered (id, channel_id, [date])
);


insert t values 
(1, 1, '2017-01-10'),
(1, 2, '2018-02-05'),
(1, 1, '2019-03-07'),
(1, 2, '2020-03-15'),
(2, 1, '2018-01-17'),
(2, 1, '2019-07-20'),
(2, 1, '2020-01-10');

select      t1.id,
            t1.channel_id,
            t1.[date],
            prev_date_channel_id1 = c1.dt,
            prev_date_channel_id2 = c2.dt
from        t t1
outer apply (
               select   top 1 [date] 
               from     t 
               where    id = t1.id 
                        and channel_id = 1 
                        and [date] < t1.[date] 
               order by date desc
            ) c1(dt)
outer apply (
               select   top 1 [date] 
               from     t 
               where    id = t1.id 
                        and channel_id = 2
                        and [date] < t1.[date] 
               order by date desc
            ) c2(dt)
order by    t1.id, t1.[date];
```

Or possibly faster still, especially with the key changed to `constraint pk_t primary key clustered (id, [date], [channel_id])`)

```
select      t1.id,
            t1.channel_id,
            t1.[date],
            prev_date_channel_id1 = prev.c1,
            prev_date_channel_id2 = prev.c2
from        t t1
outer apply (
               select   c1 = max(iif(channel_id = 1, [date], null)), 
                        c2 = max(iif(channel_id = 2, [date], null))
               from     t 
               where    id = t1.id 
                        and [date] < t1.[date] 
            ) prev
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an index on those three columns, you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT  [T0].[id],
        [T0].[channel_id],
        [T0].[date],
        [prev_date_channel_id1] = (
            SELECT  MAX([T1].[date])
            FROM    [t] [T1]
            WHERE [T1].[id] = [T0].[id]
                AND [T1].[date] < [T0].[date]
                AND [T1].[channel_id] = 1
        ),
        [prev_date_channel_id2] = (
            SELECT  MAX([T1].[date])
            FROM    [t] [T1]
            WHERE [T1].[id] = [T0].[id]
                AND [T1].[date] < [T0].[date]
                AND [T1].[channel_id] = 2
        )
FROM    [t] [T0];
```